# How to run automated selenium test scripts using C# in AWS Lambda and integrate them Amazon CI/CD pipeline

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver-c#, aws

I have been give an task by a faculty member in which I have to run my selenium automation scripts written in C# using Visual Studio under the .Net Core on AWS Lambda and also I have been told to integrate the tests in the Amazon CI/CD pipeline. Kindly help me out or tell me the steps which I can follow to complete this tasks I know how to work with VSTS test managers but AWS is a bit unknown.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the 'answer' is that you need to learn a lot more.

You have been given an assignment that will likely require several hundred hours of study for someone not familiar with those products.  Be aware of this.

The steps I would consider taking:

- Get your free for a year aws account
- Learn how to use aws lambda - videos, books, classroom, labs, etc.
- Get your first hellowworld working with C# and aws lambda
- Learn about aws CodePipeline for CI/CD
- Implement your own aws CodePipeline
- Expand to what you actually need